# Group only if condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table with fields TYPES, AMOUNT and COMMENT

I want to group by the TYPES field, but if the 'TYPES' value is "other" AND 'COMMENT' is not empty, I want those records to show up separately.

Example result:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| types     | amount    | comment   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| type1     |     27    |           |
| type2     |     65    |           |
| type3     |     45    |           |
| other     |     4     | blabla    |
| other     |     8     | something |
-------------------------------------
```

So instead of grouping the two "other" records, I want those records to show up separately (but only if they also have a comment)

Comment: What should your columns amount and comment contain? Do you want the average amount and the concatenated comment, the sum of amounts and the minimum comment, ... ?

Comment: Not that we should have to ask, but what would the data set that produces this result set look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all rows with a given type to grouped together *unless* the type is 'Other' and the comment is not `NULL`.

A close approximation is:

```
select types,
       (case when types = 'Other' and comment is not null
             then comment end) as comment,
       sum(amount) as amount
from table t
group by types, 
         (case when types = 'Other' and comment is not null
               then comment end);
```

The only issue is that rows with `types = 'Other'` and the *same* comment will be grouped together.  To fix this correctly, you need a unique identifier on each row, which MySQL does not readily provide.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work exactly as I wanted! Grouping records with same comment is not an issue in my case.

Answer (score 2):

In your case I see two separate data sets. Try with `union all` as below

```
select types, amount,comment 
from tab
where (types = 'other' and comment is not null)
or types <> 'other'
group by types 
union all
select types, amount,comment  
from tab
where types = 'other'
and comment is null
```

Comment: You forgot to select amount  and comment  columns.

Comment: You still need to include the other types

Comment: What is that supposed to return in amount and comment? (I know that MySQL allows SELECTing columns that don't appear in the GROUP BY, but this is almost certainly not what the OP wants)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt OP included expected result with this columns

Comment: As Strawberry pointed out in their comment on the question - without the original data or additional info from the OP, it's impossible to tell how the values for amount and comment should be generated. Adding them "as-is" in the SELECT clause is quite misleading IMHO.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt that's true but I wanted to show how to separate data. Generate `amount`,`comment `   doesn't change the algorithm.